# transferring value from one page to other using java script

Tags: javascript

I have to implement following in java script/HTML

1. first page(1.html) there will be button. When the user press ok button it should open second page(2.html).
2. In page 2 (2.html) there will be one text box and button . when the user enter some value in text box and press ok button the value should be availble in the one page 1.html.

How to do it in java script/Html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 cross browser ways to do this, setting a param in the url or using a cookie. Both can be done with javascript. However, not knowing the length of the data ( and personal preference against insanely long urls ) I would recommend using a cookie.

The easiest way I have found it interact with cookies via javascript is with the jQuery cookie plugin.  https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
   //page2
   $('#okButton').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var getInput = $('#yourTextInput').val();
         $.cookie('mycookie', getInput);
   });

   //page1
   $.cookie('mycookie'); //this will return the value of yourTextInput
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the level of compatibility you require, using the HTML5 Local Storage features might be a good idea.

On your 2.html, set the value using `setItem`:

```
localStorage.setItem('aNameForYourData',data_var);
```

Then, to get it on 1.html, use `getItem`:

```
data_var = localStorage.getItem('aNameForYourData');
```

If you need support in less modern browsers, consider cookies. You can find information about using cookies [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).